# Conversion from RGB to CIELAB with a complex formula

Tags: swift, graphics, coordinate-system, swift3

```
let deltaF: TransformBlock = { f in
        let transformation = (f > pow((6.0/29.0), 3.0)) ? pow(f, 1.0/3.0) : (1/3) * pow((29.0/6.0), 2.0) * f + 4/29.0

        return (transformation)
    }
```

Says here that this expression is too complex to be solved in reasonable time. Is there any way to simplify it?

This code is meant to convert RGB colors into CIELAB colors. I've done some research online and couldn't find an updated version of that code.

```
func CIE_LAB() -> (l: CGFloat, a: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
    // Get XYZ
    let xyzT = xyz()
    let x = xyzT.x/95.047
    let y = xyzT.y/100.000
    let z = xyzT.z/108.883

    // Transfrom XYZ to L*a*b
    let deltaF: TransformBlock = { f in
        let transformation = (f > pow((6.0/29.0), 3.0)) ? pow(f, 1.0/3.0) : (1/3) * pow((29.0/6.0), 2.0) * f + 4/29.0

        return (transformation)
    }
    let X = deltaF(x)
    let Y = deltaF(y)
    let Z = deltaF(z)
    let L = 116*Y - 16
    let a = 500 * (X - Y)
    let b = 200 * (Y - Z)

    return (L, a, b, xyzT.alpha)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing that would speed it up is to not constantly calculate constant values. For example, you can replace:

```
pow ((6.0 / 29.0), 3.0)
```

with

```
0.00885645167904
```

Preferably you'll give it a name like:

```
let threshold = 0.00885645167904
```

Likewise for the other call to `pow()`. `pow()` is a very expensive function to compute, so removing it can be a big win.

Comment: Hey thanks! That worked. Apparently swift doesn't like expression with too much pow(number, power)

Comment: Swift does a lot of inferring data times for expressions. It needs to do that because it's strongly typed, so all the pieces have to be type-compatible. You have functions, multiplication, addition, boolean, and trinary operators, all in a closure. It needs to evaluate all of these so it knows whether to give you a warming. :)